# EGit deleted my workspaces

Tags: eclipse, git

So I need some serious help. I was looking into using EGit in eclipse. I created a test project and Team > share to a local git repository. I than committed the project to the repository. Cool I thought, but I didnt need this repository so I deleted it. Than my entire Project Explorer went empty and my Folder that contained all my workspaces is GONE. I am kind of freaking out right now, anyone know what to do?

Comment: EGit moves the project to the git repository and sets the Eclipse project to point to that (and does not make this at all clear when it does it).

Comment: so when I deleted the repository, I essentially deleted my project? but why would my whole workspace folder be deleted as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select Team > share Project, EGit has to move all the files of the selected project(s) to the Git repository that you selected. EGit has to to that because you can't track files with git that aren't located inside the repository.

However, this makes your workspace look empty. The whole project seems to be gone. In fact, it isnt. In some config file is noted that the project has been moved to another location.

If you delete your repository, you also delete the files in it (it is a normal directory, remember that!). That means, if you really deleted your repository and did not just removed the link to eclipse so that it doesn't display the repo anymore.

Other than that, egit doen't touch anything else. It will only move the projects that you selected, and it will move it only to the location you told egit (the selected repository).

If you are sure that you lost projects you didn't select and/or one or more completly unrelated workspaces by doing what you have written above, than i suspect you found a bug as heavy as this one: https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/commit/a047be85247755cdbe0acce6f1dafc8beb84f2ac